# Type Can only iterate over an array or an instance of java.lang.Iterable , upload image android

Tags: android, image, upload, java.lang.class

I'm a .net developer and I have been working in Visual Studio for the past 3-4 years, but now my boss asked me to create some Android app, so I have to  go back to my college time and practice my Java skills (not that good). Now, the app is prety simple: upload an image to server, view that image from a web app etc.

Now my question: I have been reading A LOT about how to do this and trying a lot of tutorials, and I have finally found a good one. It has a upload class I modified, but I keep getting this error:

```
#Description    Resource    Path    Location    Type Can only iterate over an array or an instance of java.lang.Iterable#
```

I have absolute no idea of what to do to be honest; I have search for this and found several posts but none of them really help me to solve this. The exception shows up in this line: `for (String sdPath : path)`. Here is the code:

```
public class HttpUploader extends AsyncTask<String, Void, String> {
    protected String doInBackground(String path) {
        String outPut = null;

        for (String sdPath : path) {
            Bitmap bitmapOrg = BitmapFactory.decodeFile(sdPath);
            ByteArrayOutputStream bao = new ByteArrayOutputStream();

            //Resize the image
            double width = bitmapOrg.getWidth();
            double height = bitmapOrg.getHeight();
            double ratio = 400/width;
            int newheight = (int)(ratio*height);

            System.out.println("———-width" + width);
            System.out.println("———-height" + height);

            bitmapOrg = Bitmap.createScaledBitmap(bitmapOrg, 400, newheight, true);

            //Here you can define .PNG as well
            bitmapOrg.compress(Bitmap.CompressFormat.JPEG, 95, bao);
            byte[] ba = bao.toByteArray();
            int lol=0;
            String ba1 = Base64.encodeToString(ba,lol);

            System.out.println("uploading image now " + ba1);

            ArrayList<NameValuePair> nameValuePairs = new ArrayList<NameValuePair>();
            nameValuePairs.add(new BasicNameValuePair("image", ba1));

            try {
                HttpClient httpclient = new DefaultHttpClient();
                HttpPost httppost = new HttpPost("http://path to the image upload .php file/api.upload.php");
                httppost.setEntity(new UrlEncodedFormEntity(nameValuePairs));

                HttpResponse response = httpclient.execute(httppost);
                HttpEntity entity = response.getEntity();                

                // print responce
                outPut = EntityUtils.toString(entity);
                Log.i("GET RESPONSE—-", outPut);

                //is = entity.getContent();
                Log.e("log_tag ******", "good connection");

                bitmapOrg.recycle();
            }
            catch (Exception e) {
                Log.e("log_tag ******", "Error in http connection " + e.toString());
            }
        }
        return outPut;
    }

    @Override
    protected String doInBackground(String... params) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        return null;
    }
}
```

Comment: Has my answer solved your issue? Do you have any more questions relating to this issue?

Answer (score 0):

In Java, you cannot iterate over a String like that, that's why you're getting the compile time error.

The method definition for `doInBackground()` should use varargs (the ellipsis)

```
protected String doInBackground(String... path) {
```

Which is exactly what your *empty* overridden method uses. The varargs are equivalent to an array when accessing.

Also, make sure to parameterize your [AsyncTask](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/AsyncTask.html) to avoid compiler warnings.

If you did want to iterate over 1 string (through its chars), you could do:

```
for (char c: path.toCharArray()){
}
```

Or with a simple for loop, calling `String#charAt([place])`